# Set a $_SESSION variable in foreach loop only takes last element

Tags: php, session

I am having a table in which each row is populated by a `foreach` loop. Each row has an `<a href=""></a>` tag in which i want to redirect based on the product. I would like not to have the id displayed as a parameter so i decided to set `$_SESSION` variables for each row. But it always populates the last row id in every `$_SESSION`. My Code:

```
<?php foreach ($useremails as $key => $value) {
      foreach ($value as $k => $v) {?>
<tr>
    <td class="mailbox-name"><?=$v->id;?></td>
    <td class="mailbox-name"><?=$customer->data()->Vorname;?></td>
    <td class="mailbox-name"><?=$customer->data()->Name;?></td>
    <td class="mailbox-date"><input type="hidden" name="sesmailid" value="<?=$v->id?>" /></td>
    <td class="mailbox-subject"><a href="<?php
                                     Session::put(Config::get('session/mail_id'), $v->id);
  if (isset($_GET['lang'])) {
        echo URL::clearQuery(mailbox_url()) . '?lang=' . escape($_GET['lang']);
  }else{
        echo URL::clearQuery(mailbox_url());
  }?>"><b><?=$v->Titel;?></b> - <?=substr($v->Body, 0, 40)?>...</a></td>
  <?php 
       $datefromdb = Date::extractDate($v->Datum);
       $today = date('Y-m-d');
       $date = Date::daysDifference($datefromdb, $today);


  ?>
  <td class="mailbox-date"><?=$date;?> days ago</td>

</tr>
<?php }} ?>
```

It always puts the last id. How can i resolve this?

Answer (score 2):

Its Probably because you has same `index` for `session` so its gets override every time and at last it has last `value`.

Try to create `session` `array`.

Comment: yes but in the page that the link redirects to i only want the specific id and not to have to loop through the entire array.

Comment: @brg you can't dynamically set the session based on what link they click.

Comment: so the only way is the $_GET parameter i suppose

Comment: @brg yes, use the lang as a key in an array.